# need help with rails3 route to hide controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

i have some trouble generating a route with rails 3.
here is what i got
a controller with a show method:

```
def show
   @content = Content.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
end
```

i have a field in my db called :slug, which allows me to call www.mysite.com/controller/slug
what i want to do is create a route which allows me to render the same show method but
with www.mysite.com/slug

does somebody know how to do this?
any help would be appreciated, as everything else is working fine.
thanks in advance
chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this towards the end of your your `routes.rb` file.

```
get "/:slug" => "contents#show"
```

and do this in your controller

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @content = Content.find_by_slug!(params[:slug])
  end
end
```